# How does the shell script envsetup.sh execute launch?

Tags: android, git, shell, repository, building

```
 launch 1
 Segmentation fault

** Don't have a product spec for: 'full'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```

I have tried to download different sources n repo synced. I reinstalled the Linux and then carefully did the environment, all went well till I downloaded the source and then launch.
Ok left me with no other option than to look into the shell script of envsetup.sh which is throwing this error. I would like to debug from here so I run smthing like

```
 bash --debugger build/envsetup.sh
```

But I don't know how to execute launch from here. As this script runs it gives the option for launch, will try setting the breakpoint at the source of the error.

Comment: what is the command you execute?

Comment: I set up the environment carefully just like mentioned in the Initialising the build environment. Then this..                    repo init -u http://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b gingerbread repo sync then source build/envsetup.sh
lunch .All these steps run perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We call the shell script envsetup.sh . When this script is sourced with the command

```
 source build/envsetup.sh
```

I can execute all functions in this script as commands.For anyone who might wonder . Ty